# Cross compile some nodes for friendly arm mini2440

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I have a small robot build on friendly arm mini2440 which have Wireless LAN.Now I want to build some driver nodes on it so that it can communicate with roscore. And send some sensor data use some topics.And controlled by provide some services.
Now, I am using my nodes on PC to communicate with the robot using TCP,and then get data and control
robot.
Can't I just build this nodes using ROS on my Ubuntu12.04, or I should cross compile the whole ROS
using the cross compile tool chain, and then cross my nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62294/cross-compile-some-nodes-for-friendly-arm-mini2440/) by [AnsonTao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4563/ansontao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the friendly arm supports Ubuntu, you should be able to compile and run ROS nodes on it.

I suggest you start with the debs for Ubuntu ARM: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0